# Printing PDF from Chromium using Playwright Inspector(Python)

Tags: python, automation, chromium, playwright

So I am trying to execute the print out of a pdf using python with Playwright inspector in Chromium browser. After the code executes the last line item "page1.locator("#submitter").click()" PDF window opens up which Playwright inspector does not recognize or  record the print process of that when I click the print icon then select the printer then button print. Here is my code just looking for suggestion on how to do this either print or save the pdf that opens in a new window? The pdf window that pops up in Chromium is called "Locator("embed")" it also has an http address. I can provide more detail if requested.

```
from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, sync_playwright, expect


def run(playwright: Playwright) -> None:
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context()
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto("https://system.fakewebsite.com/pages/customerlogin.jsp")
    page.get_by_placeholder("Email address").click()
    page.get_by_placeholder("Email address").fill("faslse@gmail")
    page.get_by_placeholder("Password").click()
    page.get_by_placeholder("Password").fill("false")
    page.get_by_role("button", name="Log In").click()
    page.wait_for_load_state("networkidle")
    page.get_by_role("row", name="PRODUCTION Choose account", exact=True).get_by_role("link").click()
    page.wait_for_load_state("networkidle")
    page.get_by_placeholder("6-digit code").fill("335502")
    page.get_by_label("Submit").click()
    page.wait_for_load_state("networkidle")
    page.get_by_role("link", name="Reports", exact=True).click()
    page.wait_for_load_state("networkidle")
    page.get_by_role("link", name="Payments : by Cashier").click()
    page.wait_for_load_state("networkidle")
    page.get_by_role("link", name="INV0000000").click()
    page.wait_for_load_state("networkidle")
    page.get_by_role("link", name="Invoice").click()
    page.wait_for_load_state("networkidle")
    page.get_by_role("link", name="License #LIC0000000").click()
    page.wait_for_load_state("networkidle")
    with page.expect_popup() as page1_info:
        page.locator("#custpage_print_button").click()
    page.wait_for_load_state("networkidle")
    page1 = page1_info.value
    page1.get_by_role("row", name="License", exact=True).get_by_role("radio").check()
    page1.locator("#submitter").click()

with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    run(playwright)
```